# Как в теле запроса soap указать элемент boolean?

Tags: java, soap

Вот тело запроса по схеме:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
     <Authorization xmlns="http://www.example.ru/">
       <User>string</User>
       <Pass>string</Pass>
     **<Save>boolean</Save>**
     </Authorization>
  </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

В java я использую библиотеку saaj. 
в коде формирую новое сообщение soap и добавляю туда юзер и пасс, а вот как передать туда boolean не могу понять.

```
        //Сначала создаем соединение
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnFactory
                = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection connection
                = soapConnFactory.createConnection();

        //Затем создаем сообщение
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();

        //Создаем объекты, представляющие различные компоненты сообщения        
        SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
        MimeHeaders headers = message.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", 
                          "http://www.example.ru/Authorization");

        //Формирование тела сообщения
        //Создание главного элемента с учетом пространства имен
        SOAPElement bodyElement = body.addChildElement(envelope.createName("Authorization", "",
                "http://www.example.ru/"));
        //Добавление содержимого
        bodyElement.addChildElement("User").addTextNode(username);
        bodyElement.addChildElement("Pass").addTextNode(password);
        **вот здесь необходимо передать параметр 'Save' с признаком true**//

        //Сохранение сообщения
        message.saveChanges();
```

Comment: А чем Вам `bodyElement.addChildElement("Dave").addTextNode("true")` не нравится?

Comment: нет, такой вариант не нравится ибо soap сервер addTextNode("true") это воспринимает как тест. Ему (серверу soap) требуется именно boolean. )))) Получается что вместо int можно передавать "1", но ведь в описании схемы не просто так же стоит 
<Save>boolean</Save>

Comment: Мне просто интересно, а как вы различаете в выходном XML документе, значение элемента string или boolean, если оно в любом случае будет выглядеть вот так: `<Save>true</Save>`

Comment: Согласен, все банально должно быть, я просто думал что это я туплю и надо передавать именно логическую операцию, потому и спросил может такая существует? на самом деле дело в принципе вообще не в этом оказалось.